# simple way of setting up a 2 step form with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html form where the user fills in parcel details and then it outputs a price based on various fields. Then what I want is if the user is happy with the price they can fill in a few more fields such as name, contact info etc and then press submit and the form will get processed via php.

I thought of 2 ways of doing this. First is to have one form and when that is submitted it will generate another form asking for more info. But I need a way of passing variables from the first form to the second so that's not very good.

The second idea was to have a trigger in the form so that when a user changes the value in a certain field it will output the price and then show the other contact info fields. But I'm not sure if this approach is good either.

What's the simplest/smartest way to approach this on client side?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the second option.

Step 1. Make a server-side processing page, say quote.php

Step 2. Using javascript, monitor changes to your form fields. Once you have a valid entry, send the post data to quote.php, which should reply back with the quote. Populate a div with the price quote.

JQuery Example:

```
//You'll have to call this function whenever the user input changes
//Call quote service
$.get("/quote.php", 
  { 
    //Pass javascript variables as POST/GET variables
    zip: txtzip, weight: txtweight, ship_method: txtship_method 
  },

  // Populate price div on this page with the quote response
  function(data){
    $("#calc-price").html(data);
  });
```

Step 3: If the user likes the price, they fill out the rest of the form and you process it like a regular ol' form.

Comment: The calculation of the quote price is actually done using js on the client side so I don't need to use php for that bit. I do use php when submitting the overall form to email etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the client has all the data required to perform the price calculation then I would suggest a single form with some show/hide functionality as per your second idea. Others may disagree but I only go back to the server when reading or writing. And even less so if there are webservices available.

Comment: I did this by having 2 forms. The first form outputs the price and then shows the second form. The variables are global which means the second form has access to them and is able to send them to my php page.